# CSS Z-Index: How to show element above parent's sibling? (and have cousin above parent)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this project: http://jsfiddle.net/dmzq1938/3/. The generated stuff is a little messy, but it's the hovered elements I'm interested in anyway.

In the fiddle, if you hover over one of the Blue/Green/Grey rectangles in the top row, you can see what the issue is. But if you hover over one on the bottom row, you can see how it *should* look.

I understand the whole Z-Index relying on it's parent's relationship with it's siblings and I have tried making it so that on hover it makes the whole row a z-index above the others, however the problem then becomes that you can have one clicked on, and hover over another at the same time so you have a row overlapping.

What I want is to be able to click and/or hover over the boxes and the tooltip bubble to appear over the top of all the boxes. Ideally without having to put all the tooltips on the same level as the whole row!

For Completeness sake:

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.routetimeline .bars > div.stop, .routetimeline .bars > div.driving, .routetimeline .bars > div.break', function () {
    var AllDivs = $('.routetimeline .bars > div');
    AllDivs.removeClass('selected');
    var AllBalloons = $('.routetimeline .bars div.balloon');
    AllBalloons.hide();
    AllBalloons.css('box-shadow', '0');
    var ThisDiv = $(this);
    var ThisBar = ThisDiv.parent();
    var ThisBalloon = ThisDiv.next('.balloon');
    if (ThisDiv.hasClass('selected')) {
        ThisDiv.css('z-index', 'auto');
        ThisDiv.removeClass('selected');
        ThisBalloon.hide();
        ThisBalloon.css('box-shadow', '0');
    } else {
        ThisDiv.css('z-index', '100');
        ThisDiv.addClass('selected');
        ThisBalloon.show();
        ThisBalloon.css('box-shadow', '1px 1px 2px 1px #7A7A7A');
    }
});
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.routetimeline .bars > div.stop, .routetimeline .bars > div.driving, .routetimeline .bars > div.break', function () {
    var ThisDiv = $(this);
    if (!ThisDiv.hasClass('selected')) {
        ThisDiv.css('z-index', '100');
        var ThisBalloon = ThisDiv.next('.balloon');
        ThisBalloon.show();
        ThisBalloon.css('box-shadow', '1px 1px 2px 1px #7A7A7A');
    }
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.routetimeline .bars > div.stop, .routetimeline .bars > div.driving, .routetimeline .bars > div.break', function () {
    var ThisDiv = $(this);
    if (!ThisDiv.hasClass('selected')) {
        ThisDiv.css('z-index', 'auto');
        var ThisBalloon = ThisDiv.next('.balloon');
        ThisBalloon.hide();
        ThisBalloon.css('box-shadow', '0');
    }
});
```

I am quite aware I might be asking for the impossible, because logically it is. All "Outside-the-box" attempts considered!

Comment: When you click a box, the tool tip remains. When I click another box, should there now be 2 boxes? Or should the first click be replaced by the second? In other words, what is the maximum number of static tooltips at any given time?

Comment: Only one active via clicking, but another hover should be able to show a second.

Comment: Got it. Are you keen to retain the markup? You have over 4K lines of HTML. This can be greatly reduced, which would simplify the solution

Comment: The markup is generated with ASP.Net, so ideally as much as possible because it's generated when looping through various service calls.

Comment: sorry, various _complicated_ service calls. However if it needs changing or can be improved, I'll see what I can do to switch things around :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/deannorth/naLLwqjk/1/

js

```
ThisDiv.closest('.row').css('z-index', '2');
```

css

```
.row{
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}
```

This is close to what you are after. To get the tooltips to work correctly you need to z-index the parent rows.

However, doing it this way means that you have a different problem when you click roe 3 for example, then hover over row 4 or 5. You then have a row over the static tooltip.

Your best bet withoug changing markup would be to have the tooltip stay open when the user clicks it, but then hide the static tooltip when they hover over another element. This means that they would only ever be alowed one tooltip open at a time, but it would mean that you dont run into the issue described above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but to quote my question: _"I have tried making it so that on hover it makes the whole row a z-index above the others, however the problem then becomes that you can have one clicked on, and hover over another at the same time so you have a row overlapping."_. Unfortunately I can't change the tooltip click/hovering because ultimately there will be another process caused by the click and the tooltip relates to the other state change :(.

Comment: Sorry, I did read your entire question, then went to fiddle and forgot that part. My bad. It looks like you are going to have to insert the tooltip outside of the rows so they are at the .routetimeline level.

Comment: I realise this, but then I'll have issue of the positioning of them... :(

Comment: Give me a minute. I am creating a new fiddle

Comment: I think you might have just had the same brainwave I have just had... xD

Comment: Yep, I was right! But that's a lot better better than what I was about to do (make the tooltip append the routetimeline). Once I've implemented this in my code (99.99% sure I will be able to) I'll come and accept your answer. I would kiss you if I wasn't homophobic. Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could redeem myself after my earlier read fail :-)

Comment: 21 hours until I can award the bounty :(.

Comment: Oh and I had to make a few changes such as where the offset was coming from (and in turn tidied my code up). http://jsfiddle.net/aguura9s/4/

Comment: Nice work. I don't know if you noticed but I added pointer-events:none to the tooltips. If you need to have hyperlinks or any click events on the tooltips you will need to remove that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66409/discussion-between-jamie-barker-and-dean-north).